# Elixir/Phoenix passing current date through hidden_input

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I need to pass the current date into the form in the HTML so then the controller will use that info.

```
<%= form_for @changeset, statistic_path(@conn, :create), fn f -> %>
<%= hidden_input f, :date_from, value: @time_insert.year, class: "form-control" %>
<%= hidden_input f, :date_to, class: "form-control" %>
<%= submit "today", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Here I have @time_insert, which is:

```
time = Ecto.DateTime.cast!(:calendar.local_time())
time_insert = Ecto.DateTime.cast!({{time.year, time.month, time.day}, {time.hour, time.min, time.sec, time.usec}})
```

and my controller for the form:

```
def create(conn, %{"statistic" => %{"date_from" => %{"day" => day_from, "month" => month_from, "year" => year_from}, "date_to" => %{"day" => day_to, "month" => month_to, "year" => year_to}}}) do

  date_from = Ecto.DateTime.cast!({{year_from, month_from, day_from}, {0, 0, 0, 0}})
  date_to = Ecto.DateTime.cast!({{year_to, month_to, day_to}, {23, 59, 59, 0}})
```

I'm struggling with the syntax/way to push current date from @time_insert into the form to use in controller. Appreciate any advice. I've checked the Phoenix.Html.Form but still can't make it work:(

PS: I made map in controller that way, because I use following variables: date_from, date_to for further query.

Comment: Why don't you set the date in the controller? It seems like a bad idea to set it in the form. You shouldn't trust client side input.

Comment: Hey @Mohamad, the reason is, I have a search page, where user inputs date_from and date_to(with <%= date_select f ... %>), and then with that date I return all the items from db, created between that period. However, here I'm thinking of a button "Today", when you click (instead of selecting manually date_from, date_to), it will return all the items created today. Hope it explains what i need!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment, if you want to set a "Today" option in the form, you still shouldn't have to set the date, especially on the client side.

One way you can do this is to set a flag and look for it in the controller. If it's present, filter the search by today's date. Otherwise, fall back to the provided range or do not filter.

In pseudo-code:

```
def create(conn, %{ "foo_params" => foo_params } do
  case date_range = Map.get(foo_params, "today")
    {:ok, _today} ->
      # filter by today
  _ ->
    # handle other scenarios
  end
end
```